# Android. Send text to facebook messenger by Facebook SDK 4.X

Tags: android, sendmessage, facebook-sdk-4.0, facebook-messenger

As document from facebook, we can send image from android app to facebook messenger like below.

```
String metadata = "{ \"image\" : \"trees\" }";
ShareToMessengerParams shareToMessengerParams =
    ShareToMessengerParams.newBuilder(contentUri, "image/jpeg")
            .setMetaData(metadata)
            .build();

// Sharing from an Activity
MessengerUtils.shareToMessenger(this, 0, shareToMessengerParams);
```

But I want to send just text. So I tried below.

```
ShareToMessengerParams shareToMessengerParams =
    ShareToMessengerParams.newBuilder(null, "text/plain")
            .setMetaData("text to send")
            .build();

// Sharing from an Activity
MessengerUtils.shareToMessenger(this, 0, shareToMessengerParams);
```

When I tested this, java.lang.NullPointerException: Must provide non-null uri exception occurs.

How can I send message to facebook messenger..? Using Intent is not available now, so I need to use facebook sdk 4.X.

Comment: did you find answer for this? I also have same problem...

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [Facebook Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android)

Facebook (and Messenger) doesn't not allow sharing text only.