# Send message via Fb Messenger

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-messenger

How to use properly Facebook SDK to send text message with Messenger? I found similar question but there aren't any answer [Android. Send text to facebook messenger by Facebook SDK 4.X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30259813/android-send-text-to-facebook-messenger-by-facebook-sdk-4-x) Also I read Messenger documentation https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger/android but there I coundn't find the answer.

Comment: This is what I was exactly seeking for. Waiting for the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second link you supplied makes clear there are only a limited number of supported mime types, the first link also illustrates there is no support for text/plain.

The SDK is for sharing alternative content on messenger, it's not for allowing creation of new messenger clients or bots

So the TL;DR is: You cannot send text messages