# Cannot send image+text to Facebook Messenger from Android app

Tags: android, facebook, share

I wrote the following code to share image+text to a person via Facebook Messenger from my Android app:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is the text I want to send");
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(new File(inviteImage)));
sendIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION);
sendIntent.setType("image/*");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

But what happens is that, although the image does show up in the chat, the text does not. Can someone please tell me what I can do about this so that I am able to send both image and text via Facebook from my Android app?

Answer (score -1):

Follow the steps at the link: 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android

it will helps you.

Comment: I already have the Facebook App ID, Android Key Hash, and other things given in that doc. It is just a guide regarding how to enable sharing to Facebook possible from your own app. Which is already enabled. Which is why the image is going in the first place. I just want to know why the text is not going along with the image, and what I must to do make it possible.

Comment: checkout this post :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30259813/android-send-text-to-facebook-messenger-by-facebook-sdk-4-x